# CSS written in .less file is not getting applied on Landing Page

Tags: javascript, java, jakarta-ee, less

CSS written in .less file is not working on landing of the page. In background, I am getting below error -

```
org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: Cannot call method "charAt" of undefined (/D:/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/deploy/myapp.ear/myapp-web.war/WEB-INF/lib/lesscss-engine-1.5.1.jar/META-INF/less.js#308)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3687)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3665)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.typeError(ScriptRuntime.java:3693)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.typeError2(ScriptRuntime.java:3712)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.undefCallError(ScriptRuntime.java:3731)c
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.getPropFunctionAndThisHelper(ScriptRuntime.java:2258)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.getPropFunctionAndThis(ScriptRuntime.java:2251)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.Interpreter.interpretLoop(Interpreter.java:1317)
        at script.getLocation(/D:/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/deploy/myapp.ear/myapp-web.war/WEB-INF/lib/lesscss-engine-1.5.1.jar/META-INF/l
ess.js:308)
        at script.LessError(/D:/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/deploy/myapp.ear/myapp-web.war/WEB-INF/lib/lesscss-engine-1.5.1.jar/META-INF/les
s.js:335)
```

*Note*: My project is using "lesscss-servlet-1.5.1.jar" and "lesscss-engine-1.5.1.jar".

Comment: can you show your code? do you have the maven dependencies?